# A2212-15t 930kv brushless motor voltage limit

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

So here's the thing,
I am planing on buying those brushless motors (a2212-15t 930kv motor) and I was planning to use it with 5 li-ion battery. I was gonna do this until I saw the line saying: No of cells: 2-3 Li-Po. I'm not able to find any reference to those. I do see someone using a2212 brushless motor at 5s but not the 15T.

This is what I have currently
Battery: 5s battery pack (18.5 v)
ESC: 30A (Model doesn't matter)
Controller: Arduino (Just for testing. Gonna move it to a FC later)

The circuit diagram? I don't have but it's pretty simple. A motor wired to an ESC which is connected to a Arduino and a battery pack.

Will the motor power on with 5s? If so, will there be a side effects to this?

EDIT: this is the motor
[https://www.amazon.com/WST-Brushless-Outrunner-Multicopter-Quadcopter/dp/B01DC8SAOO](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01DC8SAOO)

Answer (score 1):

Speed is proportional to voltage. The kv is 930 RPM per volt. With the 11.1 volts maximum recommended voltage the no-load speed is 10320 RPM. With your proposed 18.5 volts, the no-load speed will be 17,200 RPM until something fails.

Answer (score 0):

Lower KV value means that this motor is suited for bigger propellers, that turn slower than small ones. Applying a 5s will overload the ESC and/or it will destroy the prop due to high revs. Perhaps using a 2212 1800KV or even 2300KV is more clever idea if you think that the 2212 930KV is the right one and all you need is the same spec. motor working on higher voltage.

examples:

-Racerstar 2306 BR2306S 1722KV

-Racerstar 2207 BR2207S  1600KV
and so on...